# How do i get the public IP for my Sesam Instance

Tags: sesam

I need to get the external IP for my Sesam instance, for firewall reasons. It's not available through the GUI and i do not have ssh to the box.

Is there any other way of doing this except contacting support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the URL system to achieve this, there are multiple ways but this is the one i've used.

Add the following system:

```
{
  "_id": "IP",
  "type": "system:url",
  "url_pattern": "http://ip-api.com/%s"
}
```

Add the following pipe:

```
{
  "_id": "ipjson",
  "type": "pipe",
  "name": "IP",
  "source": {
    "type": "json",
    "system": "IP",
    "url": "json"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "_id", "External-IP"],
        ["rename", "query", "IP"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This should output to the "ipjson" dataset and you will find the IP there.

Note that your IP might be subject to change.